# How to extract a rectangular and non-rectangular area from a video?

Tags: c#, kinect

I am developing a face tracking application using Kinect, and I have output like the following.

[image: faceTracking]

What I want to do is the extract the exact face area, either the yellow-lined area or the red rectangular, it would be great if you can tell me how to do both. Basically, I am expecting an output with only the interested area with black otherwise.

Right now I have all the point coordinates that I need, but I am not sure which class and method to use.

Please note that I am working with video frames, if it makes any difference.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in C#, but in c++, running something like this generates an array of RGB values:

```
const XnRGB24Pixel *pImage = imageMD->RGB24Data(); // generate array
XnRGB24Pixel pixelRGB = *pImage; // get the first element of array
byte red = pixelRGB.nRed // read the RED value
```

The array is 1-dimensional and elements are stored in it row wise from the bottom (last row, then the row before last row, ...). Going through them with a nested for loop like this would give you the rectangular area you want:

```
for(int y = RECTANGLE_Y1; y < RECTANGLE_Y2; y++)
{
    for(int x = RECTANGLE_X1; x < RECTANGLE_x2; x++)
    {
        pixelRGB = pImage[y*RESOLUTION_WIDTH + x]; // get the element
        // work with pixelRGB
    }
}
```

Replace RECTANGLE_X1 and RECTANGLE_Y1 with the coordinates of the lower left edge coordinates of your rectangle and RECTANGLE_X2 and RECTANGLE_Y2 with the upper right edge coordinates.

For getting the values of pixels inside the non-rectangular area, a similar approach would work if you can figure out the geometric calculations necessary to recognize when a given [x,y] are inside the area; but even after that, I don't have any clue on how to store it in conventional data structures.

Hope this helps.